# Javascript how to get pixel colour from image data

Tags: javascript, image, pixel

How can I determine what colour an image is from it's data? I used Sharp to crop a single pixel to the buffer a single pixel out:

```
img.onload = resizeImg;
img.src = 'image.png';

function resizeImg() {
  this.path = this.path = 'image.png';

  sharp(this.path)
  .resize(this.width * 2, this.height * 2)
  .extract({ width: 1, height: 1, left: 250, top: 100 })
  .toBuffer({ resolveWithObject: true })
  .then(({ data, info }) => {
      console.log(data);
  })
}
```

The data is

A single black pixel:

```
0: 137
1: 80
2: 78
3: 71
4: 13
5: 10
6: 26
7: 10
8: 0
9: 0
10: 0
11: 13
12: 73
13: 72
14: 68
15: 82
16: 0
17: 0
18: 0
19: 6
20: 0
21: 0
22: 0
23: 6
24: 8
25: 2
26: 0
27: 0
28: 0
29: 111
30: 174
31: 120
32: 31
33: 0
34: 0
35: 0
36: 9
37: 112
38: 72
39: 89
40: 115
41: 0
42: 0
43: 11
44: 18
45: 0
46: 0
47: 11
48: 18
49: 1
50: 210
51: 221
52: 126
53: 252
54: 0
55: 0
56: 0
57: 12
58: 73
59: 68
60: 65
61: 84
62: 8
63: 215
64: 99
65: 96
66: 160
67: 55
68: 0
69: 0
70: 0
71: 114
72: 0
73: 1
74: 235
75: 156
76: 163
77: 230
78: 0
79: 0
80: 0
81: 0
82: 73
83: 69
84: 78
85: 68
86: 174
87: 66
88: 96
89: 130
```

And a single red pixel:

```
0: 137
1: 80
2: 78
3: 71
4: 13
5: 10
6: 26
7: 10
8: 0
9: 0
10: 0
11: 13
12: 73
13: 72
14: 68
15: 82
16: 0
17: 0
18: 0
19: 6
20: 0
21: 0
22: 0
23: 6
24: 8
25: 2
26: 0
27: 0
28: 0
29: 111
30: 174
31: 120
32: 31
33: 0
34: 0
35: 0
36: 9
37: 112
38: 72
39: 89
40: 115
41: 0
42: 0
43: 11
44: 18
45: 0
46: 0
47: 11
48: 18
49: 1
50: 210
51: 221
52: 126
53: 252
54: 0
55: 0
56: 0
57: 34
58: 73
59: 68
60: 65
61: 84
62: 8
63: 215
64: 99
65: 184
66: 196
67: 200
68: 112
69: 153
70: 145
71: 225
72: 10
73: 3
74: 195
75: 85
76: 24
77: 98
78: 160
79: 166
80: 208
81: 101
82: 70
83: 198
84: 43
85: 140
86: 140
87: 87
88: 25
89: 16
90: 8
91: 0
92: 196
93: 122
94: 29
95: 230
96: 197
97: 156
98: 124
99: 21
100: 0
101: 0
102: 0
103: 0
104: 73
105: 69
106: 78
107: 68
108: 174
109: 66
110: 96
111: 130
```

The data for just a single pixel buffered image is not as simple as I thought it would be so not sure how to identify these colours.

Comment: _"The readonly `ImageData.data` property returns a `Uint8ClampedArray` that contains the `ImageData` object's pixel data. **Data is stored as a one-dimensional array in the RGBA order, with integer values between 0 and 255 (inclusive)**."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data))

Comment: @Andreas If that's the case, why are most of the values the same for these two different colours? The first half of the array is identical in fact. The last 12 numbers are too.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you've posted in your question. I just added the relevant part when working with a canvas and the `ImageData` available from it. Add a [mcve] and we might be able to help you. Right now that's just a list of numbers...

Comment: @Andreas It's a buffered image, I'm not using canvas.

Comment: @Andreas Update answer with the formula used to get the data from the image into the buffer.

Comment: And `sharp()` is what? Please add a [mcve] !

Comment: @Andreas I didn't think we could give links in questions so I didn't link to it. I thought there was only one Sharp for javascript. Anyway this is what it is: https://github.com/lovell/sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the program didn't explicitly specify a format for the `data` output, `sharp` generated the output in the same format as the image source.  In this case the input format was PNG, so your `data` buffer content is also in PNG format.  That's why the first 8 bytes of `data` are the standard PNG file header, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header

To get the `data` output formatted as a collection of pixels, regardless of whatever the image source's format might have been, replace

```
    .toBuffer({resolveWithObject: true})
```

with

```
    .raw()
    .toBuffer({resolveWithObject: true})
```